# How to update an SKScene programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So, I have a SKScene in swift that I want to completely erase, as in remove all sprites so I can redraw it from scratch. Is there a built in method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you are looking for is:

```
removeAllChildren()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restart from scratch, you can use *Initialization* to achieve this as stated by the Swift Documentation:

> Initialization is the process of preparing an instance of a class, structure, or enumeration for use.

```
myScene = MySceneClass(someSize)
```

Or, if you don't need to restart from start, create a *reset* method that reset only what you want to reset.

At last, if your need is to remove all the sprites then use `removeAllChildren()`.